# Tuning table select SQL having a RAW column in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have a table with several columns and a unique RAW column. I created an unique index on the RAW column.

My query selects all columns from the table (6 million rows).

when i see the cost of the query its too high (51K). and its still using INDEX FULL scan. The query do not have any filter conditions, its a plain select * from.

Please suggest how can i tune the query operation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the actual query and the explain plan?

Comment: select /*+ index (rawdata idx_test) */ rawdata.* from v_wis_cds_cp_rawdata_test rawdata

Operation Object Name Rows Bytes Cost Object Node In/Out PStart PStop

SELECT STATEMENT Optimizer Mode=CHOOSE  5 M   379898                           
  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID WIS.V_WIS_CDS_CP_RAWDATA_TEST 5 M 1G 379898                           
    INDEX FULL SCAN WIS.IDX_TEST 5 M   23532

Comment: I deleted my answer as it was not applicable.

Comment: You say "the cost is too high", but "cost" in itself is meaningless.  How long is the query actually taking?

Comment: You're accessing every column from every row of your table.  How could you possibly get it any faster than the time it takes to read each row from the database (i.e. a full table scan)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why are you hinting it to use the index if you're retrieving all columns from all rows? The index would only help if you were filtering on the indexed column. If you were only retrieving the indexed column then an `INDEX_FFS` hint might help. But if you have to go back to the data for any non-indexed columns then using the index at all becomes counterproductive beyond a certain proportion of returned data as you're having to access both the index data blocks and the table data blocks repeatedly.

Comment: I would add the word "repeatedly" to the end of your answer. But still +1.

Comment: Indeed. The explain plan shows the full index scan and the individual table access by rowid, and if it's looking at the data in index order it's likely to be jumping about within table data blocks so it'll look at each block multiple times. Might be in the buffer but can't assume that.

Answer (score 3):

So, your query is:

```
select /*+ index (rawdata idx_test) */
       rawdata.*
from   v_wis_cds_cp_rawdata_test rawdata
```

and you want to know why Oracle is choosing an INDEX FULL scan?

Well, as Alex said, the reason is the "`index (raw data idx_text)`" hint. This is a directive that tells the Oracle optimizer, "when you access `rawdata`, use an index access on the `idx_text` index", which means that's what Oracle will do if at all possible - **even if that's not the best plan**.

Hints don't make queries faster automatically. They are a way of telling the optimizer what *not* to do.

I've seen queries like this before - sometimes a hint like this is added in order to return the rows in sorted order, without actually doing a sort. However, if this was the requirement, I'd strongly recommend adding an ORDER BY clause in anyway, because if the hint becomes invalid for some reason (e.g. the index gets dropped or renamed), the sorting would no longer happen and no error would be reported.

If you don't need the rows returned in any particular order, I suggest you remove the hint and see if the performance improves.